# Set IP_HDRINCL to setsockopt function in win32

Tags: c++, winapi, sockets, setsockopt

I'm fighting with raw sockets in Win32 and now I'm stuck, the soetsockopt function give me the 10022 error (invalid argument), but I think I pass the correct arguments... of course I'm wrong u_u'

```
sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,IPPROTO_UDP);
if (sock == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
  printf("Error socket(): %d", WSAGetLastError());
  return;
}
char on = 1;
error =  setsockopt(sock,IPPROTO_IP,IP_HDRINCL,&on,sizeof(on)); 
if (sock == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
  printf("Error setsockopt(): %d", WSAGetLastError());
  return;
}
```

Anybody knows what happen to my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember you need to use `int on = 1` instead of char...

Comment: It's true! :D Thank you Artyom!

Answer (score 2):

You should use DWORD 1 or bool true, there are lots of documents that show code with char, int, DWORD, bool, but the right one is book or DWORD, maybe int in some systems... but currently it worked for me as bool.

By the way, I've found error 10014 WSAEFAULT when executing the same function setsockopt with IP_HDRINCL in Win7, it works in XP but in Win7 it always fails and don't know why... maybe it is disabled in recent windows versions?